# Replacing each point in a point feature with a specific shaped polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, polygon, modelbuilder, point

I have many random points in one layer. I want to replace each individual point with a specific shaped polygon like the image below illustrates.

Kind of like applying some sort of irregular buffer to each point.

The reason for this is that I want to identify where symbols that have the shape of the polygon I intend to use overlap.

Is this possible? I would like to apply this to several thousand points at once also. Maybe with python, model builder or FME?

[image: Example]

Comment: Are the attributes of the points driving these irregular shapes? Do you need the actual polygons for analysis, or just display? Symbology has you covered for the latter.

Comment: If you want to visualize where points are clustered together, have you considered creating a heatmap instead?

Comment: Maybe you should transfer your Point attributes to the Polygon layer using a Spatial Join. I'm pretty sure you cannot update a Point geometry with a Polygon geometry if your data is in Shapefile or Geodatabase. Esri does not allow mixed geometry types. Each feature class has a defined feature type, that cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Should be possible. As you mention python i guess you have some knowledge there.

The idea would be to read your point coordinates. Then create the shape of your desired buffer. You can build a loop for creating a shape for each point and within this loop you move your polygons to the coordinates of your points(as you have always the same shape it is easy to just calculate the delta x/y for the center of your shape)

At the end you can use an intersect to have the overlaping areas.

Comment: This sounds good but unfortunately my python experience is next to none.

Comment: Mhh in this case its a good oportunity to start ;) Maybe someone else will have an other idea (modelbuilder will also be possible, but its not that easy as well as you have to combine 2 models as only one iterator for one model is supported). Otherwise i don´t think that anyone will post you a ready to use script, as this is not the intention of answering a question. This would be kind of a support service.